How to setup 7.1/5.1 channel USB sound card on Android
I'm trying to setup 7.1/5.1 channel USB audio card on my RPI4 (I'm using KonstaKang's ROM konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS21 (Android 14). I found some info on the web that suggest multichannel audio is supported:
How to play 5.1 audio direct to speakers?
I tried editing /vendor/etc/usb_audio_policy_configuration.xml as suggested but still get only stereo output.
Could you please point me what can I check/change to make this work?
Update: I found that after the update of usb_audio_policy_configuration.xml actually there is sound from all 8 channels when adjusting the sound level from Settings but when playing video with VLC (AC3 5.1 audio) there is still only stereo on the main two channels.

What Android version is installed on your Raspberry and which ROM do you use (to my knowledge there is no official raspberry ROM).

@ Robert there is official ROM but in my experience it doesn't play well with Android // There are a bunch of Android ROMs, so OP would probably be better asking in Raspberry SE since there are few Questions and Answers here on this site //Besides, the hardware configurations of Pi, ROM peculiarity and Android version all contribute to complexity//I had a tough time getting Android Bluetooth paired

@beeshyams: That "official ROM" is not Android, but a Debian-based conventional Linux, Raspberry Pi OS.

@John I am aware of that :) //I also said in the comment that there are a bunch of Android ROMs, never said there is an official ROM for Android

I'm using KonstaKang's ROM https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS21/ (Android 14).

@DimitarKosev When requested additional info or clarification, make sure to always [edit] the question to add it, not just comments.

Ok for the others looking to do the same as me, apparently the sound card works (Creative Soundblaster X3 but any USB card that works on Linux should do too), with the above configuration and outputs 7.1/5.1 surround. The actual issue is that most players output only stereo. I was testing with VLC that happens to be broken and does not output multi channel audio. KODI, MPV and Nova player do output proper 5.1/7.1 surround.   Tested with KonstaKANG AOSP 13/14 builds, Lineage21 and the multichannel sound works.
